# Sending a dynamic jsp/html page as an email.

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-mail

Posted this in another forum, thought of posting here as well. 
I need to send a jsp/html page, that is generated as a report, as an email. How do I do it?
If it's a static html page, I can hard code it as a string variable and set it as one of the arguments in the setContent method as follow:
message.setContent(stringValue,"text/html"), but how do I do it for a page that is actually a report, meaning it's contents are dynamic. Hope somone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Use a templating engine, like [Velocity](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html), to dynamically replace variables. Depending on tools and frameworks you already use, there might even be some ready-made helper classes. I know Spring has emailing features with built-in Velocity support.